# How to concatenate columns on top of each other in an array

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have the following array:

```
a = np.array([[1,3,5,2,3],[3,2,5,6,7],[1,7,3,6,5]]);
```

How can I stack the columns on top of each other to form a single column vector to produce the following?

```
b =np.array([[1], [3], [1], [3], [2], [7],[5],[5],[3],[2],[6],[6],[3],[7],[5]]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [reshape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) function and the transpose [`.T`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) operator

```
np.reshape(a.T, (a.size,1))
```

Comment: I am so sorry! I accidentally put the wrong array for `b` in my question. Could you have a look again? I have edited my question. I actually meant to stack the columns vertically on each other and not the rows. Sorry again!

Comment: You will need to transpose `a` before the reshape.

Comment: Thanks @kazemakase!

Comment: Or use this answer with the `order='F'` keyword added.

Answer (score 1):

You can flatten the transposed array, create a new axis, and transpose again.

```
>>> np.ravel(a.T)[None].T
array([[1],
       [3],
       [1],
       [3],
       [2],
       [7],
       [5],
       [5],
       [3],
       [2],
       [6],
       [6],
       [3],
       [7],
       [5]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `'F'` for Fortran order together with `ravel` or `reshape`:

```
a.ravel('F')[:, None]
# array([[1],
#        [3],
#        [1],
#        [3],
#        [2],
# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

To stick with the stacking idea, a list of `a.T` is:

```
In [87]: list(a.T)
Out[87]: 
[array([1, 3, 1]),
 array([3, 2, 7]),
 array([5, 5, 3]),
 array([2, 6, 6]),
 array([3, 7, 5])]
```

which can then be concatenated on the one axis

```
In [90]: np.concatenate(a.T)
Out[90]: array([1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 7, 5, 5, 3, 2, 6, 6, 3, 7, 5])
```

And turn it into a column vector by adding a dimension:

```
In [91]: _[:,None]
Out[91]: 
array([[1],
       [3],
       [1],
       [3],
       [2],
       [7],
       [5],
       [5],
       [3],
       [2],
       [6],
       [6],
       [3],
       [7],
       [5]])
```

It may be worth noting that `a.T`, the transpose, is produced by changing the order to `F`.  So this is a variation on the `a.ravel(order='F')` approach.  In order to stack the columns it has to reorder the elements of the array (default is 'c' row oriented).

Answer (score 0):

The shortest is `a.T.reshape(-1,1)`  :

- `a.T` for the good layout,
- `reshape` for the good shape, with one column.

or equivalent : `a.reshape(-1,1,order='F')`.